# How to host my ASP.NET core site on IIS (in development environment, without deploy / publish)

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, c#-3.0

I used to host my ASP.NET sites (not core) on IIS locally, in my development environment.
Doing it helped me avoiding from using IIS Express (It's very uncomfortable to start & stop IIS express every time).
In this way all I had to do is to rebuild and refresh the site.
My goal is to work with ASP.NET core in the same way.
I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x and it didn't go well.
What I'm looking for is to do it without deploy / publish after every C# code change (that requires building).
I use ASP.NET core 2 & IIS 10

Comment: Did you ever find a good way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: I've just found article from may https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . Did not tryed that yet. If I will then I send more info

Answer (score 6):

If you need to debug an application, you can configure the ASP.NET Core application as the default IIS startup.

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support#configure-the-project

Create a new launch profile to add development-time IIS support. In Visual Studio's **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project and select **Properties**. Select the **Debug** tab. Select **IIS** from the **Launch** dropdown. Confirm that the **Launch browser** feature is enabled with the correct URL.

Or

Alternatively, manually add a launch profile to the **launchSettings.json** file in the app:

```
{
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/WebApplication2",
        "sslPort": 0
    }
},
"profiles": {
    "IIS": {
        "commandName": "IIS",
        "launchBrowser": "true",
        "launchUrl": "http://localhost/WebApplication2",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the app_offline.htm feature of the ASPNETCore module and incorporate this into your build process.

But you need to publish your site and run IIS site/virtual app from that folder, not the project folder.

In the example below, we're publishing the site to a folder "published-site", relative to the sln location, but only for a Debug build.

I'm also assuming that the build process takes longer than it takes to spin down the process.

1. Create a PreBuild target that creates the app_offline.htm file in the publish folder.

   ```
   <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
     <Exec Command="IF EXIST &quot;$(SolutionDir)published-site&quot; (&#xD;&#xA;  echo. 2&gt;&quot;$(SolutionDir)published-site\app_offline.htm&quot;&#xD;&#xA;)" />
   </Target>
   ```
2. Create a PostBuild target that deletes the app_offline.htm file and then calls dotnet publish.

   ```
   <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
     <Exec Command="IF EXIST &quot;$(SolutionDir)published-site\app_offline.htm&quot; (&#xD;&#xA;  del &quot;$(SolutionDir)published-site\app_offline.htm&quot;&#xD;&#xA;)&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;dotnet publish --no-build --no-restore &quot;$(ProjectPath)&quot; -c $(ConfigurationName) -o &quot;$(SolutionDir)published-site&quot;" />
   </Target>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Without deploy/publish it is not possible. But you could consider using auto deployment as a workaround. For instance you could use some extensions like [Auto Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lennyomg.AutoDeploy), or by [extending the MSBuild process](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/03/24/publish-webdeploy-automatically-with-vs-build/).

Comment: Development time IIS support for ASP.NET Core Applications was introduced in July 2017 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/. So, saying "Without deploy/publish it is not possible" in Dec 2017 was misleading.

Answer (score -1):

you need Install the ASP.NET Core Module/Hosting Bundle,and Confirm the process model identity has the proper permissions,more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio